# How do I add a blank line between merged files

Tags: python, pandas

I have several CSV files that I have managed to merge. However, I need to add a blank row between each files as they merge so I know a different file starts at that point. Tried everything. Please help.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="C:\\testing", outfile="C:\\done.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["Creation Date","Author","Tweet","Language","Location","Country","Continent"]
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        ins=df.insert(len(df),'\n')
        dfList.append(ins)

    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

Comment: Please make sure you format your code correctly, currently the indentation is broken, which in Python is a show stopper.

Comment: My code is working fine. It is just the blank line that I am looking to add. Just because you don't think the indentation is correct, means I get a downvote?

Comment: Not because I think it is wrong, but because [it actually is wrong](https://ideone.com/yuQgvL). The function on line 4 has no body. Starting from line 5, you lost a level of indentation. Perhaps it was only when you were writing your question, but that doesn't change the fact that it's incorrect. As such, this question lacks in quality, and to me it says you didn't spend enough effort writing it. When that changes, I will gladly reevaluate my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example script. You can use the [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) method with a non-existent key to [enlarge the `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) and set the value of the new row.

The simplest solution seems to be to create a template `DataFrame` to use as a separator with the values set as desired. Then just insert it into the list of data frames to concatenate at appropriate positions.

Lastly, I removed the `chdir`, since `glob` can search in any path.

```
import glob
import pandas


def concatenate(input_dir, output_file_name):
    file_list=glob.glob(input_dir + "/*.csv")

    column_names=["Creation Date"
        , "Author"
        , "Tweet"
        , "Language"
        , "Location"
        , "Country"
        , "Continent"]

    # Create a separator template
    separator = pandas.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
    separator.loc[0] = [""]*7

    dataframes = []
    for file_name in file_list:
        print(file_name)
        if len(dataframes):
            # The list is not empty, so we need to add a separator
            dataframes.append(separator)
        dataframes.append(pandas.read_csv(file_name))

    concatenated = pandas.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
    concatenated.to_csv(output_file_name, index=None)
    print(concatenated)


concatenate("input", ".out.csv")
```

---

An alternative, even shorter, way is to build the concatenated `DataFrame` iteratively, using the [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method.

```
def concatenate(input_dir, output_file_name):
    file_list=glob.glob(input_dir + "/*.csv")

    column_names=["Creation Date"
        , "Author"
        , "Tweet"
        , "Language"
        , "Location"
        , "Country"
        , "Continent"]

    concatenated = pandas.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
    for file_name in file_list:
        print(file_name)
        if len(concatenated):
            # The list is not empty, so we need to add a separator
            concatenated.loc[len(concatenated)] = [""]*7
        concatenated = concatenated.append(pandas.read_csv(file_name))

    concatenated.to_csv(output_file_name, index=None)
    print(concatenated)
```

---

I tested the script with 3 input CSV files:

**input/1.csv**

```
Creation Date,Author,Tweet,Language,Location,Country,Continent
2015-12-17,foo,Hello,EN,London,UK,Europe
2015-12-18,bar,Bye,EN,Manchester,UK,Europe
2015-12-28,baz,Hallo,DE,Frankfurt,Germany,Europe
```

**input/2.csv**

```
Creation Date,Author,Tweet,Language,Location,Country,Continent
2016-01-09,bar,Tweeeeet,EN,New York,USA,America
2016-01-09,cat,Miau,FI,Helsinki,Finland,Europe
```

**input/3.csv**

```
Creation Date,Author,Tweet,Language,Location,Country,Continent
2018-12-12,who,Hello,EN,Delhi,India,Asia
```

---

When I ran it, the following output was written to console:

**Console Output (using concat)**

```
input\1.csv
input\2.csv
input\3.csv
  Creation Date Author     Tweet Language    Location  Country Continent
0    2015-12-17    foo     Hello       EN      London       UK    Europe
1    2015-12-18    bar       Bye       EN  Manchester       UK    Europe
2    2015-12-28    baz     Hallo       DE   Frankfurt  Germany    Europe
0
0    2016-01-09    bar  Tweeeeet       EN    New York      USA   America
1    2016-01-09    cat      Miau       FI    Helsinki  Finland    Europe
0
0    2018-12-12    who     Hello       EN       Delhi    India      Asia
```

The console output of the shorter variant is slightly different (note the indices in the first column), however this has no effect on the generated CSV file.

**Console Output (using append)**

```
input\1.csv
input\2.csv
input\3.csv
  Creation Date Author     Tweet Language    Location  Country Continent
0    2015-12-17    foo     Hello       EN      London       UK    Europe
1    2015-12-18    bar       Bye       EN  Manchester       UK    Europe
2    2015-12-28    baz     Hallo       DE   Frankfurt  Germany    Europe
3
0    2016-01-09    bar  Tweeeeet       EN    New York      USA   America
1    2016-01-09    cat      Miau       FI    Helsinki  Finland    Europe
6
0    2018-12-12    who     Hello       EN       Delhi    India      Asia
```

---

Finally, this is what the output CSV file it generated looks like:

**out.csv**

```
Creation Date,Author,Tweet,Language,Location,Country,Continent
2015-12-17,foo,Hello,EN,London,UK,Europe
2015-12-18,bar,Bye,EN,Manchester,UK,Europe
2015-12-28,baz,Hallo,DE,Frankfurt,Germany,Europe
,,,,,,
2016-01-09,bar,Tweeeeet,EN,New York,USA,America
2016-01-09,cat,Miau,FI,Helsinki,Finland,Europe
,,,,,,
2018-12-12,who,Hello,EN,Delhi,India,Asia
```